# Firefox browser is not launching, even when we are using the latest version of Selenium WebDriver and browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, qaf

The Firefox browser is not launching in the [QMetry](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) framework with Selenium version 3.141.59. The browser version is 114.0.1 (64-bit) and the [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) version is geckodriver-v0.33.0-win32 and geckodriver-v0.33.0-win-aarch64. The [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) version is 3.0.1.

We are getting this error:

> Timed out after 0 seconds: Unable to create driver instance in 1st attempt with retry timeout of 0 seconds. You can check/set value of 'driver.init.retry.timeout' appropriately to set retry timeout on driver initialization failure.

When I run simple Selenium web automation with the same configuration, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

@ashwini As per the error you mentioned, you can adjust the value of the `driver.init.retry.timeout` property in your QMetry configuration. Increase the timeout value to allow more time for the driver initialization process. You can set it to a reasonable value based on your specific environment and requirements.

Comment: driver timeout cant be changed, its built in functionality from selenium webdriver. I ve tried even this two //new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); but didnt helped me.

Comment: @ashwinir Ok Please try to narrow down the problem by running a simplified version of your test case within the QMetry framework. Gradually add components or features from your original test case to identify the specific cause of the problem. or if there are any updates available for the QAF framework (if applicable). Updating to the latest version may include bug fixes or improvements that could resolve the issue.